# Как разрабатывать компоненты в Joomla! удобно?

Tags: php, joomla

Есть проект на Joomla!, проект находится под управлением git и хотелось бы чтобы при деплое проекта на реальный сайт не нужно было устанавливать вручную компоненты или что либо еще делать вручную.

С расширением существующих компонентов впринципе все понятно берем и дописываем то что нужно, главное не менять оригинальный код иначе он сотрется при обновлении.

Но вот с созданием нового компонента у меня затык полный. Я пробовал просто добавить файлы в /compoents и /administrator/components и сделать
небольшую миграцию в /administrotor/components/com_admin/sql/updates которая бы в #__extensions сделала запись о новом компоненте, но этот метод у меня не заработал джумла не видит компонент таким образом созданный

Дальше я пробовал удалять и ставить новый компонент но тут у меня тоже ничего особо не получается компонент ставится потом я его найти не могу чтобы удалить.

Вопрос к разработчикам на Joomla! подскажите пожалуйста как вы разрабатываете компоненты? вы ведь их не переустанавливаете все время? я не могу понять этот механизм. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо проще всего будет поставить свой компонент один раз, закомитить изменения и при равзертывании где-либо придется заходить в Поиск расширений и устанавливать расширение